# Error 403 Apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I keep getting this error message when I try to access something on my page.

Access Forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Error 403

I am using Windows 7, and this is Apache 2.4.

```
<Directory /> 
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xammpp2/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp2/cgi-bin">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Is there anything in the apache error_log? Are you running apache as a service? If so, what user is the service running as? Does that user have permission to those directories?

Comment: The Apache config file looks ok, we are going to need the error log and the file you are trying to load.

Comment: isn't "C:/xammpp2/htdocs" a typo , should'nt it be "C:/xampp2/htdocs"